# AWS Classic Load Balancer + EC2: web API requests returns 404

Tags: rest, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

I have an AWS EC2 Jira instance running behind an AWS Classic load balancer. The site loads in the browser fine, but all API requests are returning 404 for some reason. It is ***not*** a Jira 404, but a generic 404 response with no body and minimal headers. Only response useful header seems to be `Server: nginx`.

Tried white-listing my client IP, opening up all ports, sending request to the LB and directly to the instance with proper security group settings, etc., but same 404 response is returned. I'm using Postman to test the API. I noticed when I load the EC2 instance directly in the browser, it redirects to the load balancer.

Returns 200 with HTML. Basic auth works, too.

```
GET http://jira (home page)
```

Returns 404:

```
GET http://jira/rest/api/2/issue/ticket-num (or any other /rest/ endpoints)
```

Where should I start looking to debug this 404 issue? I feel like I'm missing something basic. I'm not seeing any Jira configuration for setting up its rest API. I feel like perhaps it's a server configuration issue, although I've never come across manual web server configuration while installing Jira, so maybe on the AWS's side?

EDIT: still waiting to get ssh access to the instance, so I'll update as I get more info and access.

Comment: Error `404` is a "file not found" error. So the request is making it to your EC2 instance. So the solution is going to be found in your Jira configuration, not in security groups.

Comment: How many instances are you running in your load balancer? It could be that one server is down, and one is up.

Also - /rest/api/latest/issue/ticket-num is the offical rest api uri. Without the documentation in front of me, but i believe that it'll return 404 for a ticket that isn't found. Maybe check that the ticket does actually exist.

Comment: @MaraisRossouw Only 1 EC2 behind the LB. I updated the ticket on what kind of 404 it is. It's not a response from Jira, but I think it might be from either the LB or the EC2's web server.

Answer (score 0):

This HTTP 404 responses with very limited set of headers could be from the default (the bottom one) rule in ELB. I experienced similar issue getting HTTP 404 because instead of `host header` I set `path` and provided the host domain name in one of ELB rules. So the rule did not work and default rule returned 404 because there is no such path exists on the instance.

I would recommend to try to use `Redirect to` or `Return fixed response` options for default rule to check out if it goes to the default rule.